# PhoneGap camera not able to confirm after capturing an image

Tags: cordova

I'm making an app to test PhoneGap's capabilities, so that i might later use it for larger projects. I was trying to get the camera API working by building a simple test app that just captures and displays an image. The weird thing is that when i press my capture button which triggers `navigate.camera.getPicture()` I can take a picture but not confirm the picture so that the process returns to my app and gives me the captured image. All the other buttons are working as expected, so I can for example press cancel and it correctly returns back to my app and runs the function passed as second parameter to `navigate.camera.getPicture()` (the error handler).

Here is how I call `navigate.camera.getPicture()`:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture( function( uri ) {
    // code to handle success
}, function( msg ) {
    // code to handle error
}, {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
    targetWidth: 2000,
    targetHeight: 2000,
    correctOrientation: true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
} );
```

I have tried to comment out all the configuration parameters except destinationType to see if that helped.

My config.xml has these lines to allow for camera:

```
<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />
```

My debug environment is a Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.2.1.

I have also run the app under Ripple which worked exacly as expected.

The app is built with PhoneGap Build, not Android SDK on my machine, if that makes a difference.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Which version of Cordova are you using?

Comment: Latest version; 2.5.0

Comment: have you tried  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG?, does it work in other android devices?

Comment: I only have one device to test with, but I sent it to a friend as well, and he said it did not work. He did not specify what did not work, but i assume it was the same issue, since there are not too many there things there that can go wrong. Also I have tried commenting out all options except for destinationType, and as I understand from the API docs JPEG is the default, but it did not work then either.

Comment: Also, the emulator in the Android SDK behaves just like it did on my phone, so it does not seam to be device-specific. LogCat did not log any error messages either.

Comment: Have you tried removing <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" /> from config.xml?

Comment: Yes. Originally it was not there, still did not work.

Comment: I had similar issues recently using Phonegap Build and geolocation - I couldn't get my code to work at all with this platform. Eventually I built the app with an IDE and used exactly the same code as with Build and it worked fine. It doesn't help your problem directly, but it may be that you're not actually doing anything 'wrong', there's just an issue at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue running an app built with PhoneGap Build on a Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.2. I was able to solve this issue by using the following two feature directives in my config.xml:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
```

Unfortunately, there were no errors coming from logcat, but this seems to do the trick. Hope this helps!

Comment: That was it! I was missing the file feature. Thanks. Weird this was not made more clear in the documentation for PhoneGap Build.